# Closure binding $this and garbage collector

Tags: php

### Description

I've implemented a `Strategy` class representing various strategies. Each strategy, upon creation, accepts a function as a parameter. This function is then bound to the strategy, allowing the use of $this within the anonymous function. Here's an example:

```
$a = new Strategy(function () {
    $this->getName(); // Strategy 1. $this refers to $a within this function.
});
```

Within the constructor of the `Strategy` class:

```
public function __construct(Closure $strategy)
{
    self::initCounter();
    $this->strategy = $strategy(...)->bindTo($this);

    $this->name = 'Strategy ' . self::$strategyCounter->getNextStrategyNumber();
}
```

The `initCounter` method initializes counter which is simple private static field with object of `StrategyCounter` class which have only number of Strategies and method to get next number - `getNextNumber()` and to decrement number - `decrementStrategyCounter()`

The principle of operation is simple:

When creating a new Strategy, it receives the default name: "Strategy X", where X is the number of the next strategy. For example:

```
$a = new Strategy(function () {}); // Name = Strategy 1
$b = new Strategy(function () {}); // Name = Strategy 2
// and so on.
```

### Where is the problem and what I want to achive?

I also wanted the name of the Strategy to not be blocked, i.e. if the object is deleted/unset, the counter should be decremented so that the name is available for the new strategy like this:

```
$a = new Strategy(function () {}); // Name = Strategy 1
$b = new Strategy(function () {}); // Name = Strategy 2
unset($b); // $b is unset => Counter decremented => Default name for next Strategy should be with number 2.
$c = new Strategy(function () {}); // Name = Strategy 2
```

Unfortunately, I am not able to achieve this using `__destruct()` because the reference to the `Strategy` is in `Closure`

### What I tried

I thought maybe I should remove Closure first in the destructor, but that didn't work:

```
public function __destruct()
{
    unset($this->strategy);
    self::$strategyCounter->decrementStrategyCounter();
}
```

This is because the destructor is not called at all.
I understand that like this:

```
$a = new Strategy(function () {}); // Name = Strategy 1
$b = new Strategy(function () {}); // Name = Strategy 2
unset($b); // $b isn't unset, because Strategy still exists, because was bind to Closure within that Strategy, and since this is the case, no destuctor is called.
$c = new Strategy(function () {}); // Name = Strategy 3 Blehh ;C

// The script ends, all Strategies are removed one by one.
```

Comment: Side note: if you require the parameter to be a Closure, you don't need the (...) you can just call bindTo directly; on the other hand, if you *do* use the (...) you can declare the type as "callable" allowing you to pass in other things like a string representing a function name. The (...) syntax acts as short-hand for Closure::createFromCallable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can barely have a simple Interface which expects a `run()` method to exist. From that you can call it with the `$this` context. Each `$strategy` instance has it's own `$this` scope.

Demo: https://3v4l.org/eCtZU

```
interface StrategyInterface {
    public function run();
}

class Strategy implements StrategyInterface
{
    protected ?string $value = null;
    public function __construct(private Closure $closure)
    {
        $this->value = (string) rand(1, 100);
    }

    public function run()
    {
        $this->closure->call($this);
    }
}

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i) {
    $strategy = new Strategy(function() {
        var_dump($this->value);
    });

    $strategy->run();
}
```

Here a more complex using static counter:

Demo: https://3v4l.org/smcDi

```
interface StrategyInterface
{
    public function run();
}

class Strategy implements StrategyInterface
{
    protected ?string $value = null;
    private static $counter = 0;

    public function __construct(private Closure $closure)
    {
        echo "Strategy Counter: ", ++self::$counter, PHP_EOL;
        $this->value = (string)rand(1, 100);
    }

    public function run()
    {
        $this->closure->call($this);
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        echo "Strategy Counter: ", --self::$counter, PHP_EOL;
    }
}

$strategy1 = new Strategy(function () {
    var_dump($this->value);
});

$strategy2 = new Strategy(function () {
    var_dump($this->value);
});

$strategy3 = new Strategy(function () {
    var_dump($this->value);
});


$strategy1->run(); // counter still 3, because 3 are created
$strategy1 = null; // destroy the first strategy, counter is 2
$strategy2->run();
unset($strategy2); // destroy the second strategy, counter is 1
$strategy3->run();

$strategy4 = new Strategy(function () { // create a new strategy, counter is 2
    var_dump($this->value);
});

// program ends, counter goes down to 0
```

Comment: Exactly, I don't have to bind $this to Closure right away, I can do it when I execute the function, for the duration of its call, and the property will be unbound, which will enable deletion.

By the way, I already use the run function and inside it I did call_user_method($this->strategy), just replace it with $this->strategy->call($this) and remove the binding in the constructor. Simple and brilliant, thank you very much.

Comment: @LordF You also may omit the Interface, but it makes it easier to spot a mistake inside an IDE when having multiple Strategy classes which would be my approach. So  I would make a custom Strategy class which would encapsulate their "secret" function which does not need be exposed. With that you could use a Factory or Facade and inject any Strategy without needing to touch/pass a function. Example https://3v4l.org/a6aRH

Answer (score 1):

As you've worked out, the problem is that you have a *circular reference* - the strategy references the closure, and the closure references the strategy.

The destructor will *eventually* be called when [PHP checks for orphaned circular references](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.collecting-cycles.php). If there's a specific place in your code where you unset strategies, you could call [gc_collect_cycles](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gc-collect-cycles.php) after doing so to have them immediately destroyed.

Alternatively, you need to change the design to avoid circular references. For instance, rather than binding the closure to the Strategy object, pass the Strategy in as a parameter each time you invoke it:

```
// Inside Strategy class
public function invoke() {
    ($this->strategy)($this);
}

// Outside
$a = new Strategy(function (Strategy $s) {
    $strat->getName(); // Strategy 1. $strat will be passed the object $a
});
```

If you already pass parameters to the callback in the real code, just add the Strategy before them - conceptually, $this can be seen as just a parameter with special syntax.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately it is not perfect and has its drawbacks. I had a version like this before, where the Strategy was passed to the method, but I changed it because it was less intuitive.

Comment: Firstly, it may cause confusion as to why the strategy is passed to the method, because it does not clearly indicate that it is the same as the one I am creating.
 
Secondly, it requires writing morde code, which is quite important because we create a lot of strategies in the code and for all new Instance I need to write Strategy $s. And because of this, I changed it to bindTo with $this

Comment: @LordF I can totally see that it has downsides, but sometimes you have to compromise: either you have the concise code which binds a circular reference, or you have a predictable destructor fired based on reference counting. There may be another option, but I can't think what it would be.

Comment: Yes it's true. I'm currently analyzing the most minimalist example (https://3v4l.org/cZbNH) and nothing comes to mind.
Basically, I came to the conclusion that this problem is unsolvable due to the structure of PHP itself. The only solution would be if PHP allowed calling the class method while removing the variable, something like: $a->destroy(); which would also remove the $a variable itself